# quick way to generate methods to handle events in Visual Studio 2010 from markup?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, .net-4.0, event-handling, markup

In the markups, sometimes I may want to specify a particular control should have a method to handle an event.

Is there a way, that Visual Studio 2010 can automatically generate the event for me. I find it sometimes is hard for me to remember the signature.

I know I can hit the designer, but it takes ages to load and I find it a bit cumbersome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure, I understand. You can simply type in the name of a non-existing method, right click on it and choose "Navigate to event handler".
Or, even faster: Just type in the Event name followed by an equal sign and then hit TAB, when it shows the text `<New event handler>`.

Comment: ok I'm not at work anymore, so I can't verify right now, but are you saying, I could just type in OnClick="abc", right click on "abc" and it should have a "Navigate to event handler" option? I'll have to give it a try.

Comment: I just checked in Visual Studio Web Developer Express, it doesn't seem to exist there. The thing you're talking about does seem to exist when you're in the code page though, I'm referring to the ability to do that in the markup page.

Comment: actually, I guess since the controls defined in the markup are exposed in the code behind anyway, I could just do it in the code behind page to generate the method and then delete the event binding and add it back in the markup.